# How do i tell Mongoose NOT to save a field?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

How do i tell Mongoose **not** to save the `age` field if it's null or undefined?
Or could i do this in Express somehow?

**Express**

```
router.put('/edit/:id', function(req, res) {
    Person.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, {
        name: req.body.updateData.name,
        age: req.body.updateData.age
       }, { new: true });
})
```

**Mongoose Schema**

```
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String},
    age: {type: String}
})
```

An explination (if u ask why i need this)
I'm using the same html template for `new person` and `edit person`. When i create a new person, Mongoose will save just the `name` field if i leave the `age` field empty. But when i use the edit template, Mongoose will always set the `age` field as **null**, even if the field is empty. I can't think of anything to stop this.

Answer (score 0):

You could manage your request data before the db update, like:

```
router.put('/edit/:id', function(req, res) {
    let update = {name: req.body.updateData.name};
    if (req.body.updateData.age != "") {
        update.age = req.body.updateData.age;
    }
    Person.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, update, { new: true });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aioros, you answer gave me an idea, however i found this solution to match my issue. I'm just **deleteing** the null or undefined **object elements before they are send to Mongoose.**

```
let update = {
      name: req.body.updateData.name,
      age: req.body.updateData.age
     };

if (update.age === null || update.age === undefined) delete update.age

Person.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, update, { new: true });
```